# I am trying to connect android app with laravel using retrofit2. During login/register it throws error as:- java.lang.NullPointerException:

Tags: android, laravel, retrofit2, retrofit2.6

I have a problem with my android app, it crushes every time i run it. The error seems to be java.lang.NullPointerException. Here is the error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMwQz.png)

The error is java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.retrofitexample.models.DefaultResponse.getFail()' on a null object reference
at com.example.retrofitexample.activities.RegisterActivity$3.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:124)

the code at register activity is:-

```
    Call<DefaultResponse> call = retrofitClient
            .getInstance()
            .getInterfaceApi()
            .registerUser(name, email, password);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<DefaultResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Response<DefaultResponse> response) {
            DefaultResponse dr = response.body();
            if (response.code() == 201) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, dr.getSuccess(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, dr.getFail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

i tried changing few lines of code but nothing seems to work. Help please

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Fast Android Networking](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking) library, it's very simple and good way to work with PHP or Laravel.

Comment: Fast Android Networking is good for dealing with back end like PHP(Laravel)

Comment: Really thanks!! I am using (FAN) fast android networking. Its very easy to use and with alot of features, everything is working fine now in my android app